# Sum time of two datetime2 columns?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

I have a table with two `datetime2` columns which I want to add the time it took from `callstartdt` to `callenddt`.

I have tried something like this

```
select DATEADD(minute, callstartdt,callenddt) as summing
from Detail
where SeqNum =87
```

but I always end up with a error like

> Argument data type datetime2 is invalid for argument 2 of dateadd function.

I created a small example here :

```
create table detail (startdt datetime2, enddt datetime2)

insert into detail values
  ('2014-12-26 07:51:04.513','2014-12-26 07:52:38.400'),
  ('2014-12-26 07:57:13.877','2014-12-26 08:06:48.978');
```

How can I get the time it took in minutes or seconds?

I am using SQL Server 2012.

Comment: `DATEADD` can add a few **minutes** (or hours) as a **numerical** value to an existing date - you cannot "add" two dates ... what would that even really mean??? You can use `DATEADD(MINUTE, 60, callstartdt)` or something like this. [Consult the official MSDN documentation for `DATEADD` for more details!](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186819.aspx)

Comment: What would you expect adding two dates to result to? You can use `DATEPART` to get some specific items from a date to use in calculations though

Comment: Perhaps what you really want is to *subtract*? Then you might have a look  at `DATEDIFF`: `datediff(s, startdt, enddt)`.

Comment: i figure it out, i use datediff.. it seems after i post a question i end up figuring stuff out ..thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Going along with Giorgos Betsos comment. You can use something like this to get the time taken between two dates `DATEDIFF([DatePart],[date1],[date2])`. So to get the seconds it took between two dates you can do this.

```
declare @startdate datetime
declare @enddate datetime

set @startdate = '04/04/2014'
set @enddate = '06/04/2014'

select datediff(second, @startdate, @enddate)
```